# c# htmlagilitypack select first tag in nested elements

Tags: c#

this is my html code. How to select first link(a) after  each div tag

```
<div class="test">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

i've tried just using one slash :   `//div[@class="test"]/a` but it selects both

Comment: How are you using the `//div[@class="test"]/a` ?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this (using index):

```
var elements = something.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"test\"]/a[1]");
```

Comment: it selects only first div, but i have list and  want to select first a tag child from each div

Comment: copy this again note the [1] not [0]. Maybe you didn't pick the update. I have tested it. It works.

Comment: it may not a bug. maybe it is to help users who don't understand (proper) indices which start from 0.

Comment: It's not `HtmlAgilityPack` but [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) who is to blame: http://mukulgandhi.blogspot.de/2008/05/blog-post.html

Comment: @hmahdavi You're using the wrong class name. It's `c-price__value js-variant-price`. Not just `js-variant-price`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string html = @"<div class=""test"">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
  </div>");

var firstAnchor = doc.DocumentNode
     .SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'test')]")
     .SelectSingleNode("//a");
```

or with this syntax:

```
var firstDiv = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (firstDiv != null)
{
    var firstAnchor = firstDiv.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili: you can use my second approach